# Setup krfb so it starts accepting connections

Tags: kde

I'm doing my best to configure krfb to start automatically after machine starts, but even if I start it after system boots, it always starts with sharing disabled.

Is there any option I can pass on command line or option in krfbrc to make it accept connections after starting?